# Match any url which begins with a certain path element

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot v1.3.3.RELEASE and would like to write a web service which can map to any of the following:

- /foo
- /foo/a
- /foo/a/b
- /foo/a/b/c
- /bar/d
- /bar/d/e
- ...

So basically anything beginning with `/foo` or `/bar` and can any number of path elements afterwards.

I'm thinking something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/{path:(foo|bar)(/[^/]+?)*}")
@ResponseBody
public String doStuff(final String path) throws Exception
{
    // Do stuff with path
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple path segments in a `PathVariable`, but you could write something like:

```
@RequestMapping({"/foo/**", "/bar/**"})
@ResponseBody
public String doStuff(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    // Do stuff with path
}
```

Comment: Cheers pal. Thanks for your help.